# How to run a hook only after selected Cucumber scenarios?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I've written a hook to capture a screenshot of a successful test:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.passed?
    screenshot_pass = "/VVR_Browser_BDD/Test Pass/#{scenario.name}.jpeg"
    page.save_screenshot screenshot_pass
  end
end
```

This element works very well at the moment, but as my test suite grows, I'll be overrun by screenshots.  I want to pick and choose when this hook is used.

I know with a feature file, you can tag it like:

```
@happypath
When /^I log into a page$/ do
```

etc etc.

Can that same tag mechanism be used to call the hook?

I only want to run screenshots for new tests that I've written to satisfy me they're working correctly before they're integrated into my full test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling the code as part of a hook, you should be able to perform the action for tagged scenarios

```
@take_screenshot
When /^I log into a page$/ do
```

Then your hook could be called

```
After('@take_screenshot') do |scenario|
   if scenario.passed?
     screenshot_pass = "/VVR_Browser_BDD/Test Pass/#{scenario.name}.jpeg"
      page.save_screenshot screenshot_pass
  end
end
```

Comment: I was originally using this but I decided to use an alternative.  I configured my env file to contain if ENV(Save_Pass) then after do etc.  Then in cmd, i just type set Save_Pass=true.  This will only save the screenshots as long as that session of cucumber is open.